# Ошибка с slash commands, Приложение не отвечает

Tags: python, discord.py

Я сделал бота, со слеш командами на py-cord, но к сожалению, когда я пытаюсь вызвать команду, то дискорд пишет "Приложение не отвечает.", хотя если я напишу просто эту команду, то все работает прекрасно.
Код:

```
@bot.slash_command(description='Посмотреть количество игровой валюты у пользователя.')
async def bal(mes,user_id:discord.Member=None):
```

Также, если я пытаюсь ввести просто команду без использования подсказок, например не "/bal" , а " /bal" , то мне выдает результат, но после пишет, заготовленный текст "Команда не найдена."
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Я решил проблему, в коде где await ctx
Поставь respond
Должно получиться так: await ctx.respond(f'Текст')